# OpenCV logging is verbose on android

Tags: android, opencv

I am using OpenCV in my android app. CvCameraViewListener2 is generating lots of logging. How do I systematically turn off OpenCV logging on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling android logs through proguard:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```